# Mediator pattern concerns

Tags: java, swing, oop, design-patterns, mediator

I am creating a quite complicated view, where many different components have to talk to each other. I am not a master of OOP and I have just read a half of „Head First Design Patterns” and also a lot of web tutorials about design patterns. My design rather quickly become complicated and introducing mediator pattern greatly helped me with organising communication between Swing components.

But I still have some concerns about a proper implementation of it and I would like to discuss them here, hoping for some fresh ideas.

1. The design is quite complicated and many components have to communicate with mediator. Some of them are parts of object compositions, that are part of object compositions... Sometimes I am passing mediator reference to one object just to allow one of it's field to communicate with it. The obvious idea was to convert mediator instance to singleton, so I could avoid such useless passing. I have found that some people on Stack Overflow have already thought about this way of dealing with this problem, but others in comments discouraged such ideas as it introduces coupling... If it is really a bad idea how to avoid both of problems (using singleton and redundantly passing mediator to objects that only passes it to their fields)?
2. Complicated view caused implementation of mediator to be also complicated and little to much God Object. My idea was to try to cut this single mediator to a collection of more specialised (sub)mediators. But in fact I have no idea how to do such thing... Introducing mediator splitted to smaller objects can be achieved at least in two ways:

   a) separate mediators for separate groups of actions, but the problem is I am afraid that in the end I will have to pass instances of every new mediator to components as their actions can lead to many different changes. The idea of mediator is to let the components by unaware of objects that will react on their requests, but with this approach I will loose benefits of individual mediator interface.

   b) It will lead to creation of (sub)mediators which will know how to handle specific kinds of actions. I will end with only medium split of main mediator which have registered all components but will pass requests to (sub)mediators and there will be no need for changing interface that components are speaking with.

I have both of this concerns for a long time and I have read a lot of tutorials about mediator, but every time there are explained on a very simple example and without explanation of where the mediator should be created as demo are in main(). I finally decided to try here.

Comment: Can you show some of your view code that uses a mediator? Is the mediator used only in views, or also in controllers?

Comment: @JasonEvans It's Java / Swing, so views and controllers are same thing. If that is such important, I'll try to produce some description of relations between components (because for obvious reasons I cannot just show code).

Comment: In that case, I would remove the "language-agnostic" tag, since this is now a Java/Swing related question. Doing this will help others who will attempt to help you.

Comment: Maybe it would help to split up this question into 2 different parts? Part 1 about singleton and part 2 about sub-mediators.

Comment: #2: Use the mediator the same way -- in fact, it will resemble the Composite Pattern a little. Just have everything constructed with a *director* -- even *sub-directors*. When a module calls `director.fire()` on a sub-director, that director calls `director.fire()` (global/high-level director). Nobody should care if their *director* is *globalDirector* or *subDirector* -- they just know it as "`director`".